# Is there a method to choose only some specific fields of a table using Automapper or EntityFramework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, automapper

I have a table in SqlServerDatabase. Table name is User(Id,Name,Paswd) and Im using automapper in Mvc4. Now i want only specific fields or 2 fields from the table instead of whole table, using automapper.how to do??

Answer (score 0):

basically if the 2 objects have the same fields as in the little example

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Paswd { get; set; }
}
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Paswd { get; set; }
}
```

You just have to ignore the field

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Paswd, m => m.Ignore());
```

You can find a lot of usefull example and features here
[Automapepr Wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki)